# Visual Studio 2013 cannot start debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a project for school, I started it in the library on my laptop and copied all the files from the project to my PC from dropbox.

It's saying that it can not start debugging because the debug target `C:\Users\Me\Documents\etc.exe` is missing.

Please build and retry. I've looked online for the solution and the options were check the output path and configuration manager, rebuilding, make sure It's building always, etc and I tried all of it yet still my project won't build. This has happened multiple other times on other projects.

What could possibly be causing this?

Comment: So just to confirm, the file `C:\Users\Me\Documents\etc.exe` *does* exist?

Comment: do you have write permission to the C:\Users\Me\Documents\etc.exe  folder?

Comment: Can you start the app *without* debugging? You say "yet still my project won't build" - that's not the same as "cannot start debugging". The first thing to clarify is whether you're failing to build, or failing to debug.

Comment: It's pathed to the \Debug folder which has ProjectName.exe.config and ProjectName.vshost.exe but no ProjectName.exe that it says it's looking for but I don't know what to do about that.